# Gerar relatório com quebra de página na impressão

Tags: php

Tenho um `form` que gera uma lista que preciso imprimir.

Essa lista, as vezes irei **imprimir apenas algumas páginas**, então em cada página, preciso ter alguns dados:

- número da página
- saldo da página anterior
- cabeçalho de legenda
- registros
- saldo final (última página)

Exemplo:

[image: rel]

---

Em pesquisas, encontrei o [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) para imprimir de **html para PDF**, mas não sei se seria a melhor opção, e se fosse, como funciona a quebra.

Gostaria ao menos de uma direção por onde começar, o que é possível ou não fazer.

Answer (score 1):

Para **repetir informações em todas as página impressas**, é possível usar a tag `THEAD`.

[Documentação e exemplos da tag THEAD](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/tables/thead.html)

Funciona normal em **firefox/chrome**, mas para fazer o `THEAD` repetir os dados também em **IE** antigo é necessário ter o *css/hack* abaixo junto na página:

```
thead {display: table-header-group;}
```

Para fazer a impressão **quebrar página** em determinado ponto, da para usar o css `page-break-after` junto com o `media print`, definindo o page-break para algum elemento do seu html.

Exemplo:

```
@media print {
    footer {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

[Mais detalhes do page-break-after](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp)

Exemplo do page-break-after funcionando in-line:

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>

        <table style="page-break-after: always">
            <tr>
                <td>asdsadsd</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/><br/>
        <div>
            qqqqqq
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: res, tem como sem ser pelo CSS? Funciona inline esse `page-break-after: always;`?

Comment: Não sei de outra forma que não seja CSS, fora isso teria que ser programaticamente, dentro de um FOR ou algo do tipo, meio que "manual".

Comment: Sim, funciona in-line, adicionei um exemplo executável, aquele exemplo em um html só dele, ao tentar imprimir no firefox saiu o table em uma pagina e o div em outra

Comment: Então, mas irei fazer por loop. Terei que fazer contador de registros e fazer um if para adicionar a quebra por classe na tag. Se tivesse algo mais simples, eu não precisaria nem do CSS para quebrar. Vou dar uma aprofundada nisso. Mas obrigado por enquanto!

Comment: Fiz alguns testes e não entendi algumas coisas. Por que usar o `THEAD, TBODY` se irei quebrar em várias tabelas meus registros `<table style="page-break-after: always">` ? Em teste que fiz, a quebra não funciona se não inserido direto na `<table>`... é isso mesmo?